# Unable to read properties file in java

Tags: java

I have main `Class` which is `TestDriver.java`, In which I am calling `functions` such as read to excel files and all and for that, I need to give an excel file path in java so instead of hardcoding I am using Properties file and using that I am Calling my function.
For reading properties file I have given file path but I am unable to read properties file...

File: TestDriver.java

```
public class TestDriver 
{
      public static void main(String args[]){
            String filePath = "E:\\Project\\HRMSAutomation\\";

            Globals gbl = new Globals(filePath);

            // Functions.....

      }
}
```

File : Globals.java

```
public class Globals 
{
    static String filePath;

    public Globals(String path) {
        this.filePath = path;
    }

    static Properties prop = Genlib.readConfig(filePath+"config.properties");
    //readConfig is a method which will read the properties file
    public static final String LOGIN_URL = prop.getProperty("loginUrl");   
}
```

File : Config.properties

```
loginUrl = someurl....
testsRoot = tests
configFileDir = E:/Project/Automation/Data/ConfigData/
```

Error Log.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: nullconfig.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at gtlib.Genlib.readConfig(Genlib.java:96)
    at projlib.Globals.<clinit>(Globals.java:15)
    at testDrivers.TestDriver.main(TestDriver.java:89)
```

I am getting Error because filePath variable getting null value may be some mistake in `Globals.java` file

Comment: Please check the variables. I see static `filePath` and a method level variable called `filePath`

Comment: Do you use Spring framework?

Comment: @MehrdadHosseinNejad no..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im Java, `static` fields' initialization runs before the constructor. So, when it initializes, `filePath` is still `null`. Place the initialization in the constructor like this:

```java
public class Globals {
    static String filePath;
    public Globals(String path) {
        this.filePath = path;
        prop = Genlib.readConfig(filePath+"config.properties"); //readConfig is a method which will read the properties file
    }
    static Properties prop;
    public static final String LOGIN_URL = prop.getProperty("loginUrl");
}
```

Also, if this is a `static` class, I would recommend you to use a `static` methis to initialize it and not a constructor.

Comment: Actually @CoderCharmander This halfway works but again my problem remains as it is getting NullPointer on LOGIN_URL Line

Comment: Initialize it also in the constructor, _after_ you initialize `prop`.

Comment: What exactly you're saying, What should I initialize more in the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Guess you are using plain java coding style.

by following code you can load property and retrieve certain parameter

```
Properties prop = new Properties(); 
Class clazz = Object.class; 
InputStream stream = clazz.getResourceAsStream({path}/Config.properties"); prop.load(stream); 
filePath = prop.getProperty("configFileDir");
```

In case you use SpringBoot, work become much easier

Answer (score 0):

Is the `config.properties` file that exact name or `Config.properties`?

in `Globals.java` you refer to: `filePath+"config.properties"`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Genlib but below is the simple way of loading property file. The path which you have to supply is relative path of the file. For example the file could be at

> src/test/resources

so you just have to do it like below:

```
FileInputStream configFile = new FileInputStream("src/test/resources" + File.separator +  "config.properties");
Properties configProperties = new Properties();
configProperties.load(configFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file path is set in the constructor of the class, but your property object is using a static class variable, that is initialized when that variable is created.

So this means that when your property object is initialized, the file path is not set yet, so the properties is trying to open the filename of "nullconfig.properties".

Why are you storing those as static? If they are not necessary to be statics, you could move them all into class variables, and have the constructor open the property file instead.

Comment: As a hot fix. Try moving the "Genlib.readConfig" into the constructor too.

Comment: Problem is the fundamental design of the class is wrong. You are mixing statics with non statics in a weird way that will cause problems.